# Question about $\sigma$-field

Tags: measure-theory

I am working on the following question:

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a field of subset of $\Omega$ and define 
>   \begin{align*} \bar{\mathcal{A}}=\{\mathcal{A} \subset \Omega:
> >  \exists A_n \in \mathcal{A} \text{ and } A_n \rightarrow A\}
> > \end{align*} Show that $\mathcal{A} \subset \bar{\mathcal{A}}$ and
>   $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ is a field.

I was able to show that  $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ is a field. How do I show that $\mathcal{A} \subset \bar{\mathcal{A}}$? I start to belive that there is a typo in the question and instead they ask the opposite $ \bar{\mathcal{A}} \subset \mathcal{A}$

Here is my arguments to show that $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ is a field.

> Lets show that if $A \in \bar{\mathcal{A}}$ than $A^c \in
>  \bar{\mathcal{A}}$ Since,  $A \in \bar{\mathcal{A}}$ than we have that
>    $A_n \rightarrow A$ and we have that
>   \begin{align*} 
> A&=\limsup
>  A_n=\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k=\liminf A_n=\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k
>  \ge n} A_k 
> \end{align*}

So, the complement is 
\begin{align*}
 A^c&=\liminf A_n^c=\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{k \ge n}
 A_k^c=\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k^c \end{align*} 
So, we have that

> $A_n^c \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A^c_n \rightarrow A^c$. Hence, $A^c \in
>  \bar{\mathcal{A}}$.
>
> Next, check if $B_1,B_2,...B_m \in \bar{\mathcal{A}}$ than
>   $A=\bigcup_{i=1}^m B_i \in \bar{\mathcal{A}}$. We also have that for
>   each $B_i$ we have that $(\lim_{n \to \infty} B_{n,i})=B_i$. So,
>   \begin{align*} A=\bigcup_{i=1}^m B_i =\bigcup_{i=1}^m (\lim_{n \to
>  \infty} B_{n,i})=\bigcup_{i=1}^m \left (\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n}
>  B_{k,i} \right)=\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} \bigcup_{i=1}^m B_{k,i}
>  \end{align*} Now, let $A_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^m B_{k,i}$. So we have that
>   \begin{align} A=\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k \ge n} A_k \end{align} and
>   therefore $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$ is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $\mathcal{A}$ is a subset of $\bar{\mathcal{A}}$. For each $A\in \mathcal{A}$, Pick $A_n=A$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Also, does my proof look correct?